# How to play sounds with JavaFX

Tags: java, audio, javafx, media

I just started working with JavaFX. I know how the basics of it work. I tried to use the media and the mediaplayer classes to play a sound, called "sound.mp3". I am programming in eclipse, and I have the sound file in the src folder, the same folder as "(default package)". Here is my code:

```
import javafx.scene.media.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");

        String ssound = "sound.mp3";
        Media sound = new Media(ssound);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
        mediaPlayer.play();

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 450));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the error message thing from the console:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: uri.getScheme() == null!
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.locator.Locator.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Main.start(Main.java:16)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(Unknown Source) ... 1 more
```

Comment: Based on `uri.getScheme() == null`, I assume you need to provide a URI for the sound file, instead of just a filename.

Comment: "The source must represent a valid URI and is immutable. Only HTTP, FILE, and JAR URLs are supported." http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 34):

Just a working compilation of what the other answers say:

```
String musicFile = "StayTheNight.mp3";     // For example

Media sound = new Media(new File(musicFile).toURI().toString());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

Add the music file in your Project folder, alongside `bin` and `src`.

Any IDE will prompt you to add these as well:

```
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import java.io.File;
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to use JOAL for playing sound, but it played a nasty popping sound at the end of every wav file, and also proved overly-complicated just for playing sounds. This solves my problem.

Answer (score 11):

```
mApplause = new AudioClip(this.getClass().getResource("/sounds/applause.mp3").toExternalForm());
```

So this is what i used and it worked, i know it doesn't probably matter anymore but since it got in my google search while i was looking for something else i thought i would answer to it. :)

Meaning the toExternal Form it tells to form a url form of the path file.

Comment: You should use AudioClip class only for playing short audio files. It stores y the raw, uncompressed audio data for the entire sound, which can be quite large for long audio clips.

For more info: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html

Answer (score 3):

This is what I am currently using:

```
Media hit = new Media(new File(soundFilename).toURI().toString());
```

Comment: this isn't a complete answer. This isn't playing a sound.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on where is the audio file. (also it accepts only .wav)
if the clip is outside the src folder you need to use

```
new Media("file:sound.wav")
```

if it's not it's ok how are you doing

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here didn't work for me, but this did the job:

```
Media sound = new Media(getClass().getResource("sounds/sound.mp3").toExternalForm());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, it was about accesses given to javaFX. Assuming that you use IntelliJ IDEA, go to Run -> Edit Configurations, select "Modify Options", click on "Add VM Options", and paste this:
--module-path /PATH/TO/YOUR/JAVAFX/LIB --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.base,javafx.media
(Replace /PATH/TO/YOUR/JAVAFX/LIB with directory of the "lib" folder in javafx installation directory on your computer.
This is similar to what is said in this official tutorial:[Create-a-javafx-project-with-IntelliJ](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi13f_Vw4vxAhXMiVwKHeDeD4oQFjAAegQIAhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jetbrains.com%2Fhelp%2Fidea%2Fjavafx.html&usg=AOvVaw3kB77kotbrEN7Czmjd5iSl) ; But modules javafx.media and javafx.base are added.

*Note that based on my searches and experience, javaFX 11 **cannot** play .mp3 files (unlike .wav files). You may want to consider updating javaFX to 16 to play .mp3 files.*

Comment: I don't know where you found this information, but it is incorrect. JavaFX 11 [can play MP3 files](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html).